# How to change form action before form submits

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have an html form hooked up to my python backend. The form contains one file upload field.

If the file field is empty on submit, I would like form action to change to "http://localhost:5000/nofile".

If the file field contains a value on submit, I would like the form action to change to "http://localhost:5000/containsfile".

Here is what I've tried:

```
 <script>
   function formFunc(){
     if (document.getElementById("file").files.length == 0)
        document.getElementById("mainform").action = "http://localhost:5000/nofiles";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("mainform").action = "http://localhost:5000/containsfiles"
      }
</script>

  <form onclick="formFunc()" name="mainform" method="POST" action=""
     enctype = "multipart/form-data">
     <input type = "file" id="file" name = "file" />
     <input type = "submit"/>
  </form>
```

I have also tried using the onsubmit() and onclick() functions in my form but it won't work.

Comment: I don't know why to do this. You can send it to one url and check it on server  and send back different content or redirect to different url. It is more natural.

Comment: did you try to use `onclik` with button instead of form ? Button is always clicked.

Comment: maybe your code gives error. Did you check JavaScript console in web browser ?

Comment: Yeah you're right, server is the way to go, new to this so didn't think about it that way. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I would use `onclick` to display warning when user forgot to select file,and stop sending form. This way user will see his mistake without waiting for new page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made few basic mistakes:

- you forgot some `{`, `}` in function
- you don't have `id="mainform"`

Working code.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return '''<script>
function formFunc(){
  if (document.getElementById("file").files.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById("mainform").action = "http://localhost:5000/nofiles";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("mainform").action = "http://localhost:5000/containsfiles";
  }
}
</script>

<form onclick="formFunc()" id="mainform" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
   <input type="submit" />
</form>'''

app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

As for the way you format your function, you can also do it this way to avoid writing {} if you really want to ^^

```
const formFunc = () => document.getElementById("mainform").action = document.getElementById("file").files.length == 0 ? "http://localhost:5000/nofiles" : "http://localhost:5000/containsfiles";
```